# Simple way to downscale from 1080p@60 to 1080i@60

Tags: hdmi, live-recording

I have a [Canon LEGRIA HF R56](http://www.canon.co.uk/For_Home/Product_Finder/Camcorders/High_Definition_HD/LEGRIA_HF_R56/index.aspx) which only outputs `1080p@60` from its HDMI port. Are there any methods to downscale this to `1080p@30` or lower?

Googling this doesn't seem to throw up light. I guess I could use a HDMI capture device to downscale the signal, but then that would defeat the object of downscaling it, as I could just use that device to perform my capture.

I am doing this because my capture device, an [Intensity Shuttle](http://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/intensity/), has a maximum input rate of `1080p@30`.

EDIT:

From @ProfessorSparkles answer below, the HDMI output could be 1080p@50. I realize that my TV simply says 1080p as the input signal, rather than the framerate.

Comment: What camera do you have and why are you trying trying to go from 60 FPS to 30 FPS?

Comment: @ScottJamesWalter I have updated my question.

Comment: What happens when you just attempt to record to your Intensity Shuttle? Does it down-convert the frame rate automatically? Going from 60 to 30 is literally just leaving out every other frame. Can the recorder do this?

Comment: Unfortunately the Black Magic capturing devices are very picky when it comes to the video input, it has to exactly match the recording setting.

Comment: @professorsparkles Indeed, this is why I need to downscale the output from my video camera

Comment: @ScottJamesWalter The shuttle flat out doesn't accept 1080p@60, this is why I need to downscale

Comment: Unrelated to your question but out of personal interest, does the camera turn on automatically when you put in the battery? E.g. have no battery attached and it turns on as soon as it gets power from a battery.

Comment: @ProfessorSparkles You need to press the power button and then open the shutter manually.

Comment: @ScottJamesWalter Actually 60i is not just twice the frame rate of 30p, the 60 in 60i refers to fields, not frames. To put it another way, 60i is twice the frame rate of 30p half the vertical resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speaking to the Canon technical team, it seems that at the time of this writing, there is no way on this particular model of camera to change the resolution of the HDMI output.

Answer (score 1):

According to the specs on the Canon site your camera can record in 50i/p and 25p 1920x1080. Are you absolutely sure you can only get 60fps on the HDMI? Because that sounds rather weird that you get more FPS on the HDMI than the camera can actually record.

If you set the recording option to 25FPS normally on canon cameras the FPS should also apply to the HDMI output.

Comment: Something also to look for in the settings in European/United states settings. If you can toggle that, that may open more options for frame rates.

Comment: @ScottJamesWalter You mean the settings are different for different parts of the world?

Comment: @rhughes Yeah, broadcast standards are different for different parts of the world. Check out the differences between NTSC and PAL. Different frame rates, different resolution, etc.

Comment: The resolution won't change on an HD camcorder but the fps could definitely be region specific. Usually you can set NTSC/PAL sometimes you have to select a region with either PAL or NTSC. Which usually gives you the option for 60/30 and 50/25 FPS.